# Rails: calling a function from a before filter with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I am trying to use a before filter to prevent non-approved users from accessing a page.

To check for non-approved users, I have a method defined in an .rb file, in the /lib folder (I have several methods there that I was in various controllers and views). The method is check_user_for_current_approval(user_id).

In my controller, I tried the following variations (note that I am using RubyMine as an IDE, and it did not give me an indication that I had a syntax error):

```
before_filter(:only => [:new]) do |c|
    c.check_user_for_current_approval current_user.id
end
```

Which gave me the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in PaymentsController#new

private method `check_user_for_current_approval' called for #<PaymentsController:0x007ff06784f148>
```

The following syntax:

```
before_filter(:only => [:new]) do |c|
    c.send (:check_user_for_current_approval, current_user.id)
end
```

Produces this error:

```
SyntaxError in PaymentsController#new

/app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
c.send (:check_user_for_current_approval, current_user.id)
                                         ^
/app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:130: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Using this syntax:

```
before_filter(:only => [:new]) { check_user_for_current_approval(current_user.id) }
```

takes me straight to the page (filter has no effect). The different statements came from answers that I've seen on StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you tried to use a session with the `id` inside it instead of passing it as an argument in the filter? This way the sintax would be just `before_filter :check_user_for_current_approval, :only => [:new]`.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use a before_filter that calls a method with arguments. The answer provides a solution that applies to all methods, not just a single method that may be able to have the current_user.id called from within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your first method, but make `check_user_for_current_approval` public.

Also:

I think the shared `before_filter` would be better suited in the Application Controller, rather than in a lib-file. 
That would make it accessible to all controllers that extend the Application Controller, which normally all other controllers do.

Comment: Declaring it public worked. You mean putting the check_user_for_current_approval method in the application controller? That's a method that I use in some views as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a symbol to define the method to be called?

e.g. PaymentsController:

```
before_filter :check_user_for_current_approval, :only => :new

def check_user_for_current_approval; raise "Called"; end
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your answer. This will not allow me to pass a parameter to the method.